# Insert into another database after select

Tags: sql, cordova

I'm building mobile application using `Cordova`, the problem is I cannot insert data to table after I select from another table then I loop to insert data to another table. This is my code.

```
function editAction(sceneId){   
  db.transaction(function(tx){  
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM devScene WHERE sceneId ='"+sceneId+"'", [],
 showSceneName);
  });
}   

function showSceneName(tx,results){
    var len = results.rows.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        db.transaction(function(tx){    
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO devHistory (nodeId, name, type, status1, status2) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',
           [results.rows.item(i).nodeId,results.rows.item(i).name,results.rows.item(i).type
          ,results.rows.item(i).status1,results.rows.item(i).status2]);
         });
       }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you combine two statements in one: `tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO devHistory (nodeId, name, type, status1, status2) "SELECT nodeId, name, type, status1, status2 FROM devScene WHERE sceneId ='"+sceneId+"'", [], showSceneName);`

Comment: Cannot? Do you get an error with your code or is the data just not inserted?

Comment: data just not inserted